# Chrome extension background page in popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

Say I want to make a chrome extension that plays audio or video that you can play/pause. Extension page is being open from a popup.
It should be available on any tab that you go to.

As I understand chrome limits you to the **background** page that is being run like a separate tab, but *cannot be visible* and a **popup** page that gets displayed once you click on the icon.

So I wanted to know how would you go on about it.
Insofar I see it in hackish ways like:

- background -> event -> popup (audio context + "fake" audio buffer player)
- background -> localStorage -> popup (same thing)

Are there alternative solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. If you want to run an audio independently of any open tab, you have to run it in the background page.

Then you can show any kind of UI, for instance in the popup, with your custom controls. Then, use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to control the background page / update your controls in the UI.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping there was a better way, but I guess I was correct assuming it's not possible.